# Store ObjectOutputStream in FTP causes java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: java, sockets, object, serialization, ftp-client

I am trying to store an custom defined (ProjectData) Java object in a file in FTP . ProjectData class implements Serializable interface.I am using apache Commons Net FTP client.I have a custom class FtpClient , which has instance of Commons net FTP Client. I  connect , upload file,  download file, storeFileStream using this class.When I try to call 
saveProjectData function, it throws exception while executing save.writeObject(data).

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_23]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92) [:1.6.0_23]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136) [:1.6.0_23]
at org.apache.commons.net.io.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:72) [:2.2]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847) [:1.6.0_23]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1792) [:1.6.0_23]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:699) [:1.6.0_23]
```

So what is the problem in the code, I ready that connection is already closed, in the meantime of saving object.But I could not find where the bug.

```
public void saveProjectData(ProjectData data, String filePath) {
    ftpClient = new FtpClient(ftpConfig, logger);
    ObjectOutputStream save = null;
    try {
        ftpClient.connect();
        save = new ObjectOutputStream(ftpClient.storeFileStream(filePath));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }
    try {
        if (save == null) {
            ftpClient.reconnect();
            save = new ObjectOutputStream(ftpClient.storeFileStream(filePath));
        }
        save.writeObject(data);
        save.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error creating file:" + filePath);
        throw new FileTransferException("Could not create file:" + filePath, e);
    } finally {
        if (save != null) {
            try {
                save.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Error closing writer of file:" + filePath, e);
            }
            save = null;
        }
        if (ftpClient != null) {
            try {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
            ftpClient = null;
        }
    }
}

    /**
 * Stores the file in FTP
 * @param filePath
 * @return
 */
public OutputStream storeFileStream(String filePath) {
    try {
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        return client.storeFileStream(filePath);
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        log.warn("Could not store file:" + filePath, ioe);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I read that connection is already closed

No, you read (or you should have read) that the connection is already closed *by the peer.*

Possibly you have exceeded an upload limit.